# .net double d == double.MaxValue

Tags: java, .net

I'm porting a Java app to C# that makes use of

```
double x;

if (x == null) blah blah
```

`double`s in .Net aren't nullable so this needs to be changed. No big deal.

It is poor practice to test floating point numbers for equality. So if I initialize a variable

```
double d = double.MaxValue;
```

and later want to test it

```
if (d == double.MaxValue) blah blah
```

is this valid? Am I guaranteed that the test will always return true, assuming d has not been given a new value?

Comment: doubles in Java aren't nullable either.

Comment: If `null` is truly a valid state for `x` then perhaps it should be of type `Nullable<double>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Double` in Java is nullable, since it's a class and therefore a reference type, which *boxes* a `double`. You should use `Nullable<double>` or `double?` in C# (both are technically the same). `Nullable<T>` is a generic "box wrapper" for .NET value types.

Comment: Are there performance implications using either of these? Seems like my solution ought to have the best performance as it avoids boxing?

Comment: @bogusman Yes, a `Nullable<T>` is an actual object and subject of GC as well. An ordinary .NET-`Double` handles *similar to* (roughly) a primitive Java `double`. Depends on a lot of things how bad the impact is though...

Comment: @bogusman Wormbo's solution (http://stackoverflow.com/a/16844678/17713) will perhaps be faster and correct too unless `double.MaxValue` might ever be a computed non-empty value. A `double?` will express the may-be-empty semantics of your variable better though. The best choice will depend on what is more important to your project.

Comment: Thanks, Matthias and Wormbo. I appreciate the quick response. The application is on a Windows CE device and therefore I think performance is the driver.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with checking floating point values against some constant that you assigned before.

The smelly part about floats and equality comparison is trying to compare computed values or a computed value and a constant - that will likely fail due to rounding errors.